# Nested list "addition"

Tags: r, dplyr, nested-lists

I have a tibble

```
df = data.frame(col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B"), col2 = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1, 0.8, 0.2), id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3)) %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(col1 = list(col1), col2 = list(col2))
```

which looks like the following

```
| col1      | col2            | id |
|-----------|-----------------|----|
| [A, B, C] | [0.2, 0.2, 0.6] | 1  |
| [A]       | [1]             | 2  |
| [A, B, D] | [0.8, 0.1, 0.1] | 3  |
```

and some parameters

```
col1_to_add <- c("A", "C", "D")
col2_to_add <- c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
rel_ids <- c(2, 3)
```

and I want to do a kind of nested list "addition" in rows `rel_ids`, where I increase the values from `col2` "corresponding" to A, C and D by the values `col2_to_add`. More precisely, what I want to do with this data is the following:

In each row where `df$id` is contained in `rel_ids` (in this case, in rows 2 and 3)...

1. add elements from `col1_to_add` to `col1` if they are not already there, e.g.

```
| col1            | col2            | id |
|-----------------|-----------------|----|
| [A, B, C]       | [0.2, 0.2, 0.6] | 1  | <- unchanged
| [A, C, D]       | [1]             | 2  | <- [C, D] added to col1
| [A, B, C, D]    | [0.8, 0.1, 0.1] | 3  | <- [C] added to col1
```

2. increment the values from `col2` in the relevant positions

```
| col1            | col2                 | id |
|-----------------|----------------------|----|
| [A, B, C]       | [0.2, 0.2, 0.6]      | 1  | <- unchanged
| [A, C, D]       | [1.1, 0.1, 0.1]      | 2  | <- A increases by 0.1, C/D gain new 0.1 entries
| [A, B, C, D]    | [0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2] | 3  | <- A/D increase by 0.1, B unchanged, C gains new 0.1 entry
```

I feel comfortable with the first step, however I am not really sure where to start with the second step - I was wondering whether there in efficient way to do this kind of nested list addition (ideally within a Dplyr pipe) without having to store a lot of indices, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create another dataset with 'rel_ids', 'col1_to_add', 'col2_add', then do a join `by` the 'id', 'col1' after `unnest`ing the `list` columns in 'df', get the `rowSums` of the 'col2' columns in `transmute` and if needed, create list columns again by 'id'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

keydat <- crossing(id = rel_ids, col1 = col1_to_add, col2 = col2_to_add)
out <- df %>% 
   unnest(where(is.list)) %>%
   full_join(keydat, by = c("id", "col1")) %>%
   transmute(id, col1, col2 = rowSums(across(starts_with("col2")), 
      na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
   arrange(id) %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), list), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
> out
# A tibble: 3 × 3
     id col1      col2     
  <dbl> <list>    <list>   
1     1 <chr [3]> <dbl [3]>
2     2 <chr [3]> <dbl [3]>
3     3 <chr [4]> <dbl [4]>
> out$col1
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "C" "D"

[[3]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

> out$col2
[[1]]
[1] 0.2 0.2 0.6

[[2]]
[1] 1.1 0.1 0.1

[[3]]
[1] 0.9 0.2 0.1 0.1
```